# Recognizing 'select all that apply' answers as being separate in R

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataframe, from a survey I took (n=108). One of the questions (columns) contain four possible answers- another, 10. Here is my issue: when plotting either of these columns, it plots each level. The four-answer column is considered a factor with 13 levels and the 10-answer, a factor with 22 levels. Each time someone chose more than one answer, it counts as a separate level (i.e. `"A,B"`, `"A,B,C"`, etc.) My question is, how do I go about representing how many respondents chose `"A"` or `"B"` or a combination of `"A"` and `"B"` but not necessarily/only `"A,B"`, regardless of what other choices the made, if any.

I wish to plot these items correctly, as well as analyze the data by, say, how many `Female` respondents chose `"A"` versus how many `Male` respondents, and so on.

My issues:

1) `plot(data$letter)` plots 13 different bars whereas `letter` is a question with only 4 possible answers, select all that apply.

2) I can't show through analysis how many chose `"A"` if they also happened to choose another answer, because `"A","C"` isn't equivalent to `"A"`.

Solutions I'm searching for:

1) When `plot(data$letter)`, I want only four bars showing how many times each letter was chosen.

2) I need to work with all values of `"A"` in analysis, even if the respondent selected more than just `"A"`

Thank you!

Also, [How to clean and re-code check-all-that-apply responses in R survey data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489277/how-to-clean-and-re-code-check-all-that-apply-responses-in-r-survey-data) is a question I found before posting that explains it in totality, but the code is fairly advanced at my level of experience with R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you two ideas that might help for the two issues you mention. First, I create some sample data:

```
set.seed(175)
choices <- c("A", "B", "C", "A,B", "A,C", "B,C", "A,B,C")
data <- data.frame(respondent = 1:15,
                   letter = sample(choices, 15, replace = TRUE))
data
##    respondent letter
## 1           1    A,C
## 2           2    B,C
## 3           3    A,B
## 4           4      C
## 5           5    B,C
## 6           6    A,B
## 7           7      B
## 8           8      A
## 9           9    B,C
## 10         10      C
## 11         11      A
## 12         12      B
## 13         13      C
## 14         14    A,C
## 15         15  A,B,C
```

For simplicity, I used only three levels.

1) The following function can be used to plot `data$letter) directly in the way you want:

```
plot_allapply <- function(choices) {

   # convert to character
   choices <- as.character(choices)

   # split at comma and unlist
   choices_split <- unlist(strsplit(choices, ","))

   # convert back to factor and plot
   plot(as.factor(choices_split))
}
plot_allapply(data$letter)
```

[image]

It works as follows: First, the data in `letter` needs to be converted from type `factor` to `character`. (I know that it is a factor, because otherwise you would not get a plot at all.) Then, each element of the character vector is split at the commas. (Run `strsplit(as.character(data$letter), ",")` to see how this works for your data and `?strsplit` for more information.). Since this yields a list, it is converted to a character vector using `unlist`. The last line converts back to `factor` (which is needed in order for `plot` to create the right kind of plot) and  plotted.

2) There are many ways how you could work with the data in `data$letter`. If you are interested to know, which respondents chose `"B"`, you could do

```
grepl("B", data$letter)
```

This will return a logical vector that is `TRUE` whenever `"B"` is contained in a respondents answer. Thus, all of those will give `TRUE`: `"B", "A,B", "A,B,C"`.

Maybe it helps to add this information to your data frame. This could be done as follows:

```
data <- transform(data, isA = grepl("A", letter),
                  isB = grepl("B", letter),
                  isC = grepl("C", letter))
data
##    respondent letter   isA   isB   isC
## 1           1    A,C  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
## 2           2    B,C FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
## 3           3    A,B  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## 4           4      C FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## 5           5    B,C FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
## 6           6    A,B  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## 7           7      B FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## 8           8      A  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 9           9    B,C FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
## 10         10      C FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## 11         11      A  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 12         12      B FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## 13         13      C FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## 14         14    A,C  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
## 15         15  A,B,C  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: It would be difficult to explain how much this has helped me, my only other question at the moment would be, is there a method by which I can plot the counts as descending, ascending (you're plot did this by chance), or perhaps most sought for, in a manner which would sort them in the manner similar to a normal distribution, with the most numerous responses centered and amount decreasing in moving away from center? Thank you for your help, this has helped me so much!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. Sorting is possible and I will add that to my answer. But I'll only have time tonight.

Comment: @jnowat I thought about it and found a working solution. However, it is quite different from the solution that I posted above and I think it is worth a new question. You should  not ask again about the part that involves splitting up the answers that involve several letters but only about how to make a barplot of counts with the three different orderings you asked for. If you want, I can also formulate the question for you. Just let me know. If you post the question yourself, it would help, if you could add a link to the question as a comment here.