# How to read "select all that apply" ACASI data into SAS?

Tags: binary, sas

I'm using Audio Computer-Assisted Self-Interview (ACASI) data (http://www.novaresearch.com/QDS/) that includes some multiple choice, "select all that apply" values coded as binary (0100010) depending on what the participants chose:

[Raw binary data for "What kind of insurance do you have? Please select all that apply."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0hbz.png)

What is the easiest way to read this data into SAS so that it understands that multiple values were selected per participant?

Note: I looked at the answer here, [How to clean and re-code check-all-that-apply responses in R survey data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489277/how-to-clean-and-re-code-check-all-that-apply-responses-in-r-survey-data), but wonder if--since my data is already binary--I can just read it into SAS as is? I'm also not sure what the syntax is for SAS, since it obviously varies from R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide `TextDisplay` variable to 12 parameters/variables, you can use an array to create a set of variables, and using a loop, moving between variables in this array. Here you have some example:

```
data result;
    TextDisplay = "001001001000";

    array tab(*) $1 q1-q12;

    do i = 1 to dim(tab);
        tab(i) = substr(TextDisplay, i, 1);
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```